# Are there any slam packages to get 3d position and orientation of a robot?

Tags: ros, 3d-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to ask you whether or not there are some packages to get 3d position and orientation of a robot.

I am studying about legged robots and I try to have that robot climb stairs.

I am in trouble to get 3d position information especially z(height).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233258/are-there-any-slam-packages-to-get-3d-position-and-orientation-of-a-robot?/) by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe rgbd Slam with an imu and a good laser should be a good start.

---

Originally posted by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) with karma: 109 on 2016-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on 2016-04-29**:
Could you tell me the package name?

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-05-02**:
sorry I mean [rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap)

**Comment by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on 2016-07-09**:
thank you for your help.